# Comparing two object lists in Java

Tags: java, performance

I want to compare two fields in two different object lists and create another list to return it to the user. I used two `for` loops to do this operation.

Is there anyway I can improve this code? If I can, how?

I am adding my code below:

```
public List<UserTestBean> getUsersWithRoleAndAssignedStatus(String roleBuyer, String testId) {
        List<UserInfo> userInfoWithRole = rolesDAO.getUserInfoWithRole(roleBuyer);
        CriteriaBean bean = new CriteriaBean(null, "testId", Long.parseLong(testId));
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<AssignedTestRelation> relations = (List<AssignedTestRelation>) simpleQueryDAO
                .getObjectListWithCriteria(bean, AssignedTestRelation.class);
        List<UserTestBean> userTestBeanList = new ArrayList<UserTestBean>();
        for (UserInfo u : userInfoWithRole) {
            UserTestBean userTestBean = new UserTestBean();
            userTestBean.setEmailId(u.getEmail());
            userTestBean.setUserName(u.getUsername());
            userTestBean.setAssigned(false);

            if (relations.size() > 0) {
                for(AssignedTestRelation b:relations){
                    if(u.getEmail().equals(b.getUser())){
                        userTestBean.setAssigned(true);
                    }
                }
            }
            userTestBeanList.add(userTestBean);
        }
        return userTestBeanList;
    }
```

Comment: For one, you could `break` out of the second loop once you found a match.

Comment: For this go to code review... http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can use Predicate in CollectionUtils select [link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#select(java.util.Collection, org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate)) method. Which will selects all elements from input collection which match the given predicate into an output collection.

Comment: is it possible for you to return a Map<TestId, AssignedTestRelation> from `getObjectListWithCriteria`. This way you could get rid of the inner for loop

Comment: The simpleQueryDao is a generic method.. So its not possible